# Artifactory Query Language limiting the output

Tags: curl, artifactory, artifactory-query-lang

I'm running an AQL using curl:

```
curl -vv  -u 'admin':'password' -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d @e.txt http://somecompany.com:8081/artifactory/api/search/aql
```

Here's the e.txt file:

```
items.find(
    {
        "repo":{"$eq":"yum-repo"},
        "type":{"$eq":"file"},
        "name":{"$match":"*.rpm"}
    }
).include("repo", "path", "name", "@rpm.metadata.name")
```

Here's part of my output:

```
 "range" : {
    "start_pos" : 0,
    "end_pos" : 1000,
    "limit" : 1000
  }
```

It's limiting the output to 1000 i've tried to `limit(9999)` it didn't help

Answer (score 1):

Artifactory is configured by default to limit the number of results returned by an AQL query to 1000.
You can change this configuration in the `$ARTIFACTORY_HOME/etc/artifactory.system.properties` file:

```
## Maximum number of results to return when searching through the UI
artifactory.search.maxResults=500

## The backend limit of maximum results to return from sql queries issued by users. Should be higher than maxResults.
artifactory.search.userQueryLimit=1000
```

For more info see the documentation about [searches](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Searching+for+Artifacts)

Comment: Is there any option to set this value to infinity value?

Comment: No way of having infinite results. This is an integer value, so you can set it to Integer.MAX_VALUE

Comment: Is there any way to request a specific date format?  Here's my query `items.find(
    {
        "repo":{"$eq":"pd-yum-local"},
        "type":{"$eq":"file"},
        "name":{"$match":"*.rpm"}
    }
).include("repo", "path", "name", "updated", "modified", "created", "size",  "@rpm.metadata.name").limit(5)`

Comment: @user3502786 please post it as a new question